# startManagingCursor() in a service?

Tags: android, sqlite, service, android-activity, cursor

Is there a way to use the startManagingCursor() within a service instead of an activity, with the same results (as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29))?

More specifically, i would like to manage a given Cursor's lifecycle based on a service's lifecycle. For example, when the service is destroyed, it will automatically call deactivate() on the given Cursor. Also, when the service is created/starts again, it will call requery() method.

- Is it feasible by using an other
  appropriate method implemented in the
  Service.class?
- Is it feasible in some other way?
- Or, is it pointless at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the startManagingCursor() within a service instead of an activity, with the same results

No, sorry.

> Is it feasible by using an other appropriate method implemented in the Service.class?

No.

> Is it feasible in some other way?

You are welcome to write your own support code to do whatever you want. I doubt you can implement what you're seeking, though.

> Or, is it pointless at all?

IMHO, yes. Having a `Cursor` be automatically closed when the service is destroyed is not a bad idea. However, the notion of the `deactivate()`/`requery()` makes little sense to me in a service. This is also the impossible part, in that you have no place to put the deactivated `Cursor` that will be picked up by some future incarnation of your service.

Comment: @CommonsWare-Can it be done by this way..Activity ac = new Activity();
   ac.startManagingCursor(sdCur12);

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid: Absolutely not.

Comment: @CommonsWare-Why not...I m using it and getting desired reactions without any exceptions...but thinking it again can it be the moveToFirst() after it that does the magic..?? Plz reply as I am in great dilemma right now.

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid: Never create an activity via its constructor.

Comment: @CommonsWare- Ok..got it n it was definitely the moveToFirst() doing the magic..thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, you just need to Cast it to Activity

Like below 
    ((Activity) context).startManagingCursor(cursor);

Here is the complete code

```
private void getUserId(Context context) {

     AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(this,
     DatabaseDetail.TABLE_USER_REGISTRATION);
     adapterClass.Open();

     Cursor cursor = adapterClass.fetchRecords(new String[]{"USER_OID"},
     null);
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     ((Activity) context).startManagingCursor(cursor);
     }
     cursor.moveToFirst();

     adapterClass.close();

}
```